# Add of Handlebars code on click on a button in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using Ember and on a click on a button, I would like to add the following code on my page:

```
<div class="clearfix input-file-line">
    <div class="input-file-float-block">
        <button class="btn btn-info">From your computer</button>
        {{input type="file" class="styled"}}
    </div>
    <div class="input-file-float-block">
    or
    </div>
    <div class="input-file-float-block">
        {{#view "cloudUpload"}}
            <button class="btn btn-info" {{action 'showModalForCloudFiles'}} >from a cloud</button>
        {{/view}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And each time I click on the button, I would like to show this block. So for example, if a user click 3 times on the button, I would like to display 3 times this block.

Do you have any idea to do it with a clean way?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

You could create a flag to display the block or not.

```
isShowingUploadBlock: false,

actions: {
    // call this action from button
  showUploadBlock: function() {
    this.set("isShowingUploadBlock", true);
  }
}
```

And in template:

```
{{#if isShowingUploadBlock}}
<div class="clearfix input-file-line">
  ...
</div>
{{/if}}
```

If you'd prefer you can also toggle a class on the div instead.

Comment: I usually use this method but this time it doesn't work because I would like to display many times this block (each time a user click on a button)